# Rails app is showing properly only on Chrome. For Firefox and Safari, all the styles load incorrectly

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, firefox

Link --> http://leanhire.co/
I'm using an html template for the styles and I put it in /vendors/assets/

I checked on Chrome and all the styles and javascript elements of the theme were rendering properly. But when I tried loading the website on Firefox, the styles were all wrong. The padding was missing, align property is not working, tabs is not working, basically the whole thing is just wrong.

Originally, I put the stylesheets and javascripts in /vendors and I thought this was the problem, so I changed it and instead put all of the Styles and Javascript in /public/assets/ but its still not working. What is the best way to debug this issue?

Comment: So I already got the same problem, I solved setting the css file header as a css/style file with php, try to add a attribute `type="text/css"` in the <link> tag. The problem is because it's not considered a css file, but it works in my browser.

Comment: (it wasn't possible to edit my comment, then my browser is: Opera)

Comment: I tried that. Its not working. Its not working on firefox and safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your HTML is not valid. So the parsed DOM tree may be different for different browsers.

Please refer to this [list](https://html5.validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fleanhire.co%2F) of errors. Pay special attention to 1 and 3.